# How to sum and display total in a label using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am having a `grid view` as follows

```
 Quantity    Description    Rate    Total
   1             ---         10      10
   2             ---         20      40

                             Label outside the `gridview`
```

I have written a javascript to display total now I would like to display the total like `10+40` and should display as `50` like that I will have some other ways what I need is I would like to display the total sum `on Blur` event of `quantity` textbox.

[image]

My code for displaying amount `onblur` event is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function multiplication(txtQuantity, txtRate, txtAmount) {
        var weight = document.getElementById(txtQuantity).value;
        var rate = document.getElementById(txtRate).value;
        document.getElementById(txtAmount).value = weight * rate;
    }
</script>
```

In this script I would like to include the total

Comment: [Example?](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: share some code dude, create a small working demo on jsfiddle.net as Derek suggested.

Answer (score 1):

give the quantity textboxes a name like "quantity", then you can get them with:

```
document.getElementsByName("quantity");
```

give your label an id, like "total", so you can get that with:

```
document.getElementById("total")
```

use the body onload event to append eventlisteners to the onblur event of your quantity textboxes. And while you're at it, use a namespace, a singleton, so you don't clutter the global namespace, like so:

```
<script>
    var p = {
        onload: function() {
            var els_qty = document.getElementsByName("quantity");
            for(var i = 0, ceiling = qty_els.length; i < ceiling; i++) {
                qty_els[i].onblur = function() {
                    var total = 0;
                    for(var j = 0; j < ceiling; j++) {
                        total += Number(qty_els[j].value);
                    }
                    document.geTElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

to append the onload eventlistener, use the following:

```
<body onload="p.onload()">

</body>
```

you might want to do some validation on the quantity textboxes, but I leave that up to you.